# Send compressed JSON with MQTT.js

Tags: javascript, json, gzip, mqtt, inflate

I'm trying to send a compressed JSON using MQTT from the browser to a python server.
This is how I compress the original object (by using gzip-js)

```
...
if(opt.compression){
    msg = new Uint8Array(gzip.zip(msg, compressionOptions));
}
MQTTclient.publish(topic, msg);
...
```

But I get the error:

> script.js:65 TypeError: string.charCodeAt is not a function(…)
>
> EventEmitter.emit @   events.js:77
>
> sendPacket    @   client.js:51
>
> ....

The same happens if I try to publish the message as a standard typed array.
The only way to send the compressed message is by encoding it, but then I get problems on the python side.

Comment: Could you explain why you're not just letting the browser and the server do the gzip compress/decomprss for you? The browser's gzip is far superior to anything that could be written in JS, and it's already loaded in memory...

Comment: Any reason your using MQTT.js rather than the paho JS client?

Comment: @LinuxDisciple This is most likely not just about the payload between the browser and the broker, but between the broker and the subscriber. Also does gzip encoding work after the websocket protocol upgrade?

Comment: @LinuxDisciple I need to communicate between client(s) and server(s) through mqtt. I did not see yet how can this be done by using what you pointed out.

Comment: @hardillb Any reason to prefere paho client? does it support gzip compression? I cannot find anything related to this in documentation. And yes, I need to compress the payload between browser(s) and borker ad from broker to other subscribers (python servers).

Comment: @pedro.zena none of the clients will explicitly declare support for gzip compression because MQTT as a protocol doesn't care, it only carries bytes. I suggested trying the Paho client is it's the reference implementation and may behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by publishing an actual "buffer" instead of a typed Array.
This is my workaround:

```
...
if(opt.compression){
    msg = toBuffer(gzip.zip(msg, compressionOptions));
}
MQTTclient.publish(topic, msg);
...
```

I used the [typedarray-to-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedarray-to-buffer) module.